# Comparing List<mylist> by elements

Tags: java

I have two enum lists. I want to search for a string value from List in the other.

```
public class AzureFileModel {
    public String imageName;
    public String classifierClass ="";
    public double score;
}
public class WatsonFileModel {
    public String imageName;
    public String classifierClass ="";
    public double score;
}
private List<WatsonFileModel> watsonFileModelList = new ArrayList<>();    
private List<AzureFileModel> azureFileModelList = new ArrayList<>();
```

How do I compare both the lists for same image name in an efficient way??

**Current approach**

I have a list of all the image names from each list and I am checking if the image name matches the other by iterating through one list.

**Example Data**

```
AzureFileModelList
{
  [imagename=image1,class=football,score=9.87],
  [imagename=image2,class=tennis,score=9.7],
  [imagename=image1,class=tennis,score=0.87] //chances of same imagename
  [imagename=image3,class=football,score=9.87],  
}
WatsonFileModelList
{
  [imagename=image1,class=football,score=5.6],
  [imagename=image2,class=football,score=9.7],
  [imagename=image4,class=tennis,score=0.87]
}
```

**End result**

```
CombinedModelList{
 [imagename=image1,azureclass=football,azurescore=9.87,watsonclass=football, watsonscore =5.6],
 [imagename=image2,azureclass=tennis,azurescore=9.7,watsonclass=football,watsonscore=9.7]
}
```

Comment: Is the order important? Do you have duplicate image names in either list?

Comment: The imagenames may or may not be duplicate.

Comment: But is `[A B C]` equal to `[B C A]`?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need two classes with the exact same fields?

Make both one class. Then store *instances* of Azure or Watson data in one list

If you need differences in the classes, you use an abstract class for the common fields

If you want to compare the objects, you might want to try implementing the Comparable interface

Comparing images requires reading binary data, not just a filename

Comment: I am reading the two classes from two different excel files. I need to make an integrated list of both the classes. I can provide an example in the question

Comment: You don't need two classes to do that

Comment: Please check the edit. I need to create an end combined result

Comment: Or let us assume that the classes are not the same, in that case how can i compare the elements in the model to get the result??

Comment: The classes are the same. Make one `FileModel` class. Implement `Comparable`, have it check the names

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` instead of a `List` and specify as key a `String` that represents `imageName`.
`Map` retrievals are fast.

Note that it may also be a good thing to introduce a parent class to these two classes in order to manipulate them in an uniform way :

```
Map<String, FileModel> fileModelsByImageName;
```

If the order of element insertion matters, you could instantiate a `LinkedHashMap`.
Otherwise, a `HashMap` would be enough.